# Conditions required for finite Betti numbers

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was wondering what conditions are required on a topological space for it to have finite Betti numbers. I know that a compact space will have finite Betti numbers but this is a tight restriction. Do smooth Hausdorff manifolds or CW complexes have finite Betti numbers?

Comment: Not every compact space has finite betti numbers. Consider the Hawaiian earrings, for example.

Comment: Every infinite discrete space is a $0$-dimensional CW-complex whose $0$-th Betti number is infinite.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do smooth Hausdorff manifolds or CW complexes have finite Betti numbers?

Nope. Consider an infinite torus, i.e. infinite [connected sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_sum)

$$T=S^1\times S^1$$
$$X=T\# T\# T\#\cdots$$

This is a smooth Hausdorff manifold and a CW complex at the same time. But

$$H_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}^\infty$$

as you can [see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1618122/how-can-i-calculate-the-homology-group-of-an-infinite-torus-using-mayer-vietoris).

I am not aware of any reasonable condition so that Betti numbers are finite, except for compactness over manifolds, CW complexes and simplicial complexes.